# how to always open date picker to show when the page is ready?

Tags: datepicker, velo

I want to always open my datepicker without any click. is it possible? if not how can I achieve the same result using any other tool in wix?

I tried myelemnt.expand property in onready function but it didn't work. also tried using html embed but didn' t get the desired results.